# method to peek at registered api urls in autofac register controllers

Tags: asp.net, autofac-configuration, autofac-module

In attempt to debug api endpoint hit, the only information I am getting via postman is 404 with message file or directory does not exist on the server (IIS by the way).

I wish there is a way to peek at registered endpoints via Autofac register controllers.
It is part of the ContainerBuilder with code such as:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(this.GetType().Assembly).AsSelf<object>();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the `request` and `controller` which are you trying to reach?

Comment: I think this question can be applied in general such that within the project (namespace) any available controllers will be registered using above method.  And the uri routes information of all will be available if you want to retrieve them.